# How resolution , dpi ,pixel are related with each other

Tags: android, image, adobe

I am little confused about these terms 
1. Resolution
2. Dpi
3.Pixels

How pixel and resolution are related.?
and how pixel and dpi are related . ?

Suppose i have an image of 148*76 Dimension what does it means  in terms of pixel dpi and resolution ?
I think it means in terms of pixels is 148 px width and 76 pixel height . I am right ?
If so what about resolution and dpi ?
But when i opened it in Photoshop it say it has 72 resolution (Pixel/inch)
But how to determine what is the dpi of this image  using these details ?

Comment: your question will probably be moved or down voted because you have tagged it with design-patterns which is not related but it is a valid question though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference of px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) page of the developer docs, which contains the definitions you are looking for. In short:

- **Pixels** are the smallest unit you can use with any screen. One pixel is one dot on the screen.
- **Resolution** is the actual number of pixels in a screen. This number isn't as useful as you would think, because a 4" phone can have the same (or even a higher) resolution as a 10" tablet.
- **dpi** stands for **dots-per-inch**. It is the number of pixels per inch in a given screen. This is how Android determines what density bucket (low, high, etc) the device falls in.
- **dp** (aka dip) stands for **density-independent pixel**. This is what you should use for most of your layouts. This unit scales with the device's screen density.

When you make a graphic asset for an Android application, you typically take the following steps:

1. Determine which screen densities you will support.
2. Create your graphic at the highest resolution you will support
3. Export the graphic at the lower resolutions, and place them in the appropriate drawable resource folder for that density.

For example, an image that is 96x96 pixels on a extra high-density device should be 36x36 on a low density device, 48x48 on a medium-density device, and 72x72 on a high-density device.

Comment: When i create an image for my app which is the correct value for "resolution" in my "photoshop"? default is 92 but it look shelled on my app.